SwiftUI - Make sheet content top aligned with fraction detent
I want to replicate the behaviour of the sheet in Apple Maps. I've accomplished everything except for the content to be top-aligned with every detent. When the sheet is in medium or large state, everything is perfectly aligned, but with fraction(0.15) it is always in center, with content appearing with sheet expand.
Here's how the sheet code looks
struct DeviceMapSheet: View {

var device: Device
var locationName: String
var locationIcon: String

@State var showAlert = false

@ObservedObject var mapViewModel: MapViewModel

@Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                RemoteImage(device: device, size: SensioDimens.imageSize, warningSize: SensioDimens.warningSize, isDetailTwin: true, shouldCache: false)
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
                    DeviceTypeName(device: device)
                    
                    DeviceName(device: device)
                        .padding(.bottom, 2)
                    
                    Status(device: device)
                    
                    Battery(device: device)
                        .padding(.top, 2)
                }
            }
            .padding(.top, 24)
            
            SensioDivider()
                .padding(.vertical)
            
            HStack {
                if locationName != TranslationManager.shared.getNoAddressFound() {
                    RemoteImageView(
                        url: locationIcon,
                        placeholder: {
                            Image(SensioImages.pinIcon).resizable()
                                .scaledToFill()
                                .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                        },
                        image: {
                            $0.resizable()
                                .scaledToFill()
                                .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                        })
                }
                
                Text(locationName)
                    .font(SensioFonts.systemMFont)
            }
            
            Button(TranslationManager.shared.getDirectionInMaps()) {
                showAlert = true
            }
            .buttonStyle(SensioGreyButton())
            
            ActionButtons(device: device, isFromMap: true, mainViewModel: MainViewModel(), mapViewModel: mapViewModel, actionButtonsValues: SessionManager.shared.getAllowance(deviceSNNum: device.deviceSNNum).getActionButtonsValues(device: device))
                .padding(.top)
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .alert(TranslationManager.shared.getOpenMapTitle(), isPresented: $showAlert) {
            Button(TranslationManager.shared.getOpen(), role: .none) {
                self.openMap(deviceName: device.deviceName, latStr: device.posLati, lonStr: device.posLong)
                showAlert = false
            }.keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction)
            
            Button(TranslationManager.shared.getCancel(), role: .cancel) {
                showAlert = false
            }
        } message: {
            Text(TranslationManager.shared.getOpenMapText())
        }
    }
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $mapViewModel.showDeviceAction) {
        ZStack{
            Color.black.opacity(0.015).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            DeviceActionDialog(deviceAction: mapViewModel.deviceAction, show: $mapViewModel.showDeviceAction, isFromMap: true, mainViewModel: MainViewModel(), mapViewModel: mapViewModel)
        }
        .modifier(OpacityModifier())
    }
}
}
#Preview("DeviceMapSheet") {
    DeviceMapSheet(device: Device(), locationName: "Test Address", locationIcon: "", mapViewModel: MapViewModel())
}

And here's the code used to present the sheet (detentBinding = PresentationDetent.fraction(0.15)
sheet(isPresented: $showMapSheet) {
            DeviceMapSheet(device: device, locationName: mapViewModel.locationName, locationIcon: mapViewModel.locationIcon,
                           mapViewModel: mapViewModel)
            .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.15), .medium, .large], selection: $detentBinding))
            .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
            .interactiveDismissDisabled()
            .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled(upThrough: .medium))
            .modifier(SheetRadiusModifier())
        }

Here's the image of how it looks with fraction size

And with medium size

